# Resources in Internet Explorer Developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer

How can I see the `Resources` in IE 11 as it is in Chrome?

Using Developer Tools F12 in IE I can find how to see the resources there.

Comment: I don't have Windows on this box to check but the developer tools in IE are not as sophisticated or complete as in other browsers so I'm guessing what you are looking for is probably not available at all.

Comment: Network --> Details --> Cookies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use <kbd>F12</kbd> to see the resources.

Press <kbd>F12</kbd>, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. I think there you can see JavaScript, but you cannot see CSS.